# The map can't find the key

Tags: java

3q for everyone, I found a problem when I was writing algorithm homework.

it's about Hexadecimal addition and subtraction.

I need to input *0x2 0x1 0x9 0x2 0xf*

and then print the result *29*

this is my code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", 10);
        map.put("b", 11);
        map.put("c", 12);
        map.put("d", 13);
        map.put("e", 14);
        map.put("f", 15);
        long res = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] s = str.split(" ");
            for (String ss : s) {
                ss = ss.replace("0x", "").toLowerCase();
                int flag = 0;
                if (ss.startsWith("-")) {
                    flag = 1;
                    ss = ss.replace("-", "");
                }
                res +=
                        flag == 0 ?
                                map.getOrDefault(ss, Integer.valueOf(ss))
                                : 0 - map.getOrDefault(ss, Integer.valueOf(ss));
            }
            System.out.println(res);
            res = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

but show the exception when i input *0x2 0x1 0x9 0x2 0xf*

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)*
```

I don't know why the map not find the key of "f";

Comment: What makes you think it does not find a key in a map? Do you think `Integer.valueOf(ss)` is only executed when the map does not find a key? That is not the case.

Comment: The method `Integer.valueOf()` will be executed before passing its result to execute method `map.getOrDefault()`. Of cause, you can't convert 'f' to integer by that method.

Comment: thanks for everyone, I got it. I think Integer.valueOf(ss) is only executed when the map does not find a key. That is not the case. 3q!!!

Answer (score 0):

The key is found but you are trying to get an integer from the string: `Integer.valueOf(ss)`

Comment: thanks, I got it. I think Integer.valueOf(ss) is only executed when the map does not find a key? That is not the case.

Comment: The program behavior is not based on assumptions. It would be nice that you read it and understand what it does. It will always execute Integer.valueOf(ss) as there is no "if" that is checking that.

Answer (score -1):

Try sth like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", 10);
    map.put("b", 11);
    map.put("c", 12);
    map.put("d", 13);
    map.put("e", 14);
    map.put("f", 15);
    long res = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] s = str.split(" ");
        for (String ss : s) {
            ss = ss.replace("0x", "").toLowerCase();
            int flag = 0;
            if (ss.startsWith("-")) {
                flag = 1;
                ss = ss.replace("-", "");
            }
            int v = isNumeric(ss) ? Integer.valueOf(ss) : map.get(ss);
            res +=
                    flag == 0 ? v : -v;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
        res = 0;
    }
}
public static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
    try {
        int v = Integer.parseInt(string);
        return v >= 0 && v < 10;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```